# Are multiple non-nested if statements inside a VHDL process a bad practice?

Tags: if-statement, vhdl, synthesis

I use VHDL for a few months and I sometimes build that kind of process with **non-nested** if statements when I want some conditions to be evaluated sequentially :

```vhdl
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if CONDITION1 then
                (some instructions)
            end if;

            if CONDITION2 then
                (some instructions)
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
```

It seems to work well in both simulation and synthesis, but I hardly ever see that kind of structure when looking for examples on the web.
I had doubts about the sequential execution of those statements but the IEEE Standard VHDL Language Reference Manual Std 1076-2008 states :

> Sequential statements are used to define algorithms for the execution
>   of a subprogram or process; they execute in the order in which they
>   appear.

And the `if` statement is in the list of sequential statements.

Why can't I find more examples of this? Is this a bad practice?

Comment: I would recommend _not_ doing it. You can always replace the second `if` with either an `elsif` or an `else`. Why do I recommend not doing it? Because there is a chance that your synthesiser thinks that there are circumstances where neither `CONDITION1` or `CONDITION2` is true so it puts latches in, even if they are not necessary. (And if you end up with an`elsif`, to avoid latches, don't you also need an `else` or a _default assignment_.)

Comment: @MatthewTaylor Its a clocked process, so latches shouldnt be possible. I use the double if all the time with no issues because of my answer below. `CONDITION1` could be sync enable and `CONDITION2` sync reset, and it allows you to chose which signals have enable and reset separately. `if..else` forces all signals to be connected to both.

Comment: @Tricky Oh. Yes. It's a clocked process. No latches then.

Comment: CORRECTION: I would recommend _not_ doing it in a _combinational process_ for all the reasons I said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is legal, and yes, assignments are sequiential. Remember that signal assignemnts are given the last value given to them, so the final `if` "wins". So the following two codes are functionally identical.

```
process(clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    if cond1 then
      --do something 
    end if;

    if cond2 then
      -- do something else
    end if;
  end if;
end process;

-- same as this:

process(clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    if cond2 then 
      -- do soemthing else
    elsif cond1 then
      -- do something
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

There is a practical use for this. The traditional process template has a reset as an `if..else` setup:

```
-- sync process
if srst then
  a <= '0';
  b <= '0';
else
  --do something with a and b
end if;
```

This is fine, but you are forcing `a` and `b` to always have a link to srst. If you forget to put `b` in the srst branch, you'll connect srst to the enable pin of b, because you're saying in the code that the b register cannot be latched when srst is active. This forces you to put all register in the reset branch, which you may not want. So, to allow reset and non-reset signals in the same process without creating the enable link, you can use the double if:

```
--sync process
--do some logic with A and B here

if srst then  -- reset wins
  a <= '0'; 
  -- B has no link to reset 
end if;
```

This is not a style you find commonly on the internet (probably because of old tutorials always teaching the `if..else` style). But it is very common to find accidental timing links between srst and enable pins in development code using the "traditional" approach.

Comment: Is this still true when CONDITION1 and CONDITION2 are not mutually exclusive ? Because in that case you cannot replace the two sequential `if` by a combination of `if` and `elsif`.

Comment: `if..elsif` always implies priority.  The `if` condition takes precidence over the `elsif` condition. hence the two ifs should be equivalent.

Comment: I know `if` and `elsif` are exclusive, that's why I'm talking about the case where CONDITION1 and CONDITION 2 are not exclusive (in my first example), because then you cannot implement the program with an `if` and `elsif` you're forced to use two `if`...what do you think about that case ?

Comment: I cannot think of a case where two ifs cannot be done in an if/elseif. And ive never seen a case where two ifs cannot be done with if/elsif.